# Backup e redirecionamento de Hd windows server 2003

Tags: windows, servidor

Tenho um ws 2003 com um hd de 1TB cheio, e agora comprei um de 2tb para pode passar todos os arquivos de um para o outro.
O problema é que, no copy-paste ele dá erro no arquivo thumbs.< br />
E também, como faço para apenas começar a salvar arquivos no novo HD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thumbs.db é criado quando se utiliza pré-visualização de miniaturas.

Faça o seguinte, desative a opção que mostra o tipo de arquivo thumbs, sendo assim o arquivo thumbs ficará escondido e não será copiado.